# Php Gives Default Error But Does Not Give My Custom Errors - Wrongfully Says File Exceeded Limit

Tags: php, forms, filesize

I have built a File upload Form.
I have put:
* Txt File Size Limit: 100MB
* Img File Size Limit: 100MB
* Audio File Size Limit: 100MB
* Video File Size Limit: 100MB

I am not uploading anything that is higher than 100MB but get message:
"Warning: POST Content-Length of 10835360 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0".

For each file type, I have written custom error messages to be echoed should any file size exceed the limit. I am not getting my custom error messages echoed. Hence, believe I am not exceeding any the size limit on any file. Plus, I checked each file's sizes and they do not exceed 100MB.

I do not know to which type of file php is referring to. Which file is it referring to ?

Tested a few times with different files that are lesser than 100MB but no luck.

```
<?php 
//ERROR REPORTING CODES. 
//declare(strict_types=1); 
ini_set('display_errors', '0'); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '0'); 
error_reporting(0); 
//mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); 

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","followingbrowser"); 
if (!$conn) 
{ 
    $error = mysqli_connect_error(); 
    $errno = mysqli_connect_errno(); 
    print "$errno: $error\n"; 
    exit(); 
} 

$error_msg =  array();

$text_allowed_ext = array('pdf','txt','doc','docx');
$video_allowed_ext = array('mp4','wav','ogg','flv','wmv','avi');
$img_allowed_ext = array('jpeg','jpg','png','gif');
$audio_allowed_ext = array('mp3','wav');
$img_mime_type =  array('image/png','image/gif','image/jpeg','image/jpg');
$text_mime_type =  array('application/pdf','text/plain','application/msword','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
$video_mime_type =  array('video/mp4','video/wav','video/ogg','video/flv','video/wmv','video/avi');
$audio_mime_type = array('audio/mpeg3', 'audio/x-mpeg-3','audio/mpeg','audio/wav','application/octet-stream'); 

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

        $error = 0 ;    

        //var_dump($_FILES); //For debugging. 
        //Check whether the file was uploaded or not without any errors. 
        if(!isset($_FILES["id_verification_video_file"]) || !isset($_FILES['id_verification_txt_file']) || !isset($_FILES['id_verification_audio_file']) || !isset($_FILES['id_verification_img_file'])){ 
            $error_msg['all'] =  '<p class="text-danger">Please select all fields</p>';
            $error = 1;

        }else{

            $txt_file = $_FILES["id_verification_txt_file"]["name"]; 
            $video_file = $_FILES["id_verification_video_file"]["name"]; 
            $audio_file = $_FILES["id_verification_audio_file"]["name"]; 
            $img_file = $_FILES["id_verification_img_file"]["name"]; 

            //filters to check the file type extensions

            if(!in_array(pathinfo($txt_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION),$text_allowed_ext)){
            $error_msg['txt_error']= '<p class="text-danger">Invalid Extensions.Only PDF,text and DOC files are allowed';
             $error = 1;
            }

            if(!in_array(pathinfo($video_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION),$video_allowed_ext)){
                $error_msg['video_error'] =  '<p class="text-danger">Invalid Extensions.Only MP4,WAV,OGG,FLV,WMV and AVI files are allowed';
                $error = 1;
            }

            if(!in_array(pathinfo($audio_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION),$audio_allowed_ext)){
                $error_msg['audio_error']= '<p class="text-danger">Invalid Extensions.Only MP3 and WAV files are allowed';
                $error = 1;
            }

            if(!in_array(pathinfo($img_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION),$img_allowed_ext)){
                $error_msg['img_error']= '<p class="text-danger">Invalid Extensions.Only JPG,JPEG,PNG and GIF files are allowed';
                $error = 1;
            }


            //checking mime type
        if(!in_array(mime_content_type($_FILES["id_verification_img_file"]['tmp_name']),$img_mime_type)){
                $error_msg['img_error']= '<p class="text-danger">Invalid Extensions.Only JPG,JPEG,PNG and GIF files are allowed';
                $error = 1;
            }

            if(!in_array(mime_content_type($_FILES["id_verification_txt_file"]['tmp_name']),$text_mime_type)){
                $error_msg['txt_error']= '<p class="text-danger">Invalid Extensions.Only PDF,text and DOC files are allowed';
                $error = 1;
            }

            if(!in_array(mime_content_type($_FILES["id_verification_video_file"]['tmp_name']),$video_mime_type)){
                $error_msg['video_error'] =  '<p class="text-danger">Invalid Extensions.Only MP4,WAV,OGG,FLV,WMV and AVI files are allowed';
                $error = 1;
            }
            if(!in_array(mime_content_type($_FILES["id_verification_audio_file"]['tmp_name']),$audio_mime_type)){
                $error_msg['audio_error']= '<p class="text-danger">Invalid Extensions.Only MP3 and WAV files are allowed';
                $error = 1;

                echo mime_content_type($_FILES["id_verification_audio_file"]['tmp_name']);
            }

            //checking file size using filesize function

            if(filesize($_FILES['id_verification_txt_file']) > 100000000){
                $error_msg['txt_file_size_err'] = '<p class="text-danger">File size is greater then 100MB.File size should not exceed the 100MB';
                $error = 1;
            }

            if(filesize($_FILES['id_verification_video_file']) > 100000000){
                $error_msg['video_file_size_err'] = '<p class="text-danger">File size is greater then 100MB.File size should not exceed the 100MB';
                $error = 1;
            }

            if(filesize($_FILES['id_verification_audio_file']) > 100000000){
                $error_msg['audio_file_size_err'] = '<p class="text-danger">File size is greater then 100MB.File size should not exceed the 100MB';
                $error = 1;
            }


            if(filesize($_FILES['id_verification_img_file']) > 100000000){
                $error_msg['img_file_size_err'] = '<p class="text-danger">File size is greater then 100MB.File size should not exceed the 100MB';
                $error = 1;
            }


            //checking if there are no errors

            if($error == 0){ 
                $user = $user;   //username here
                $db_user = 'followingbrowser_user'; //Has to be in quotes. 
                //Feed Id Verification Video File Upload Directory path. 
                $directory_path = 'uploads/id_verifications/'; 
                //Make Directory under $user in 'uploads/videos/id_verifications' Folder. 
                $directory_path_and_user_dir = $directory_path.$user;   
                if(!is_dir($directory_path_and_user_dir)){ 
                    $db_user = 'followingbrowser_user'; //Has to be in quotes. 
                    $mode = 0755; 
                    mkdir($directory_path_and_user_dir,$mode, TRUE); //This line is correct and working even without quoting $mode. 
                }

                //making  directories of every files for respective user

                $video_directory  = $directory_path_and_user_dir.'/videos';
                $audio_directory  = $directory_path_and_user_dir.'/audios';
                $text_directory  = $directory_path_and_user_dir.'/text';
                $img_directory  = $directory_path_and_user_dir.'/imgs';

                if(!is_dir($video_directory)){ 
                    $db_user = 'followingbrowser_user'; //Has to be in quotes. 
                    $mode = 0755; 
                    mkdir($video_directory,$mode, TRUE); //This line is correct and working even without quoting $mode. 
                }

                if(!is_dir($audio_directory)){ 
                    $db_user = 'followingbrowser_user'; //Has to be in quotes. 
                    $mode = 0755; 
                    mkdir($audio_directory,$mode, TRUE); //This line is correct and working even without quoting $mode. 
                }

                if(!is_dir($text_directory)){ 
                    $db_user = 'followingbrowser_user'; //Has to be in quotes. 
                    $mode = 0755; 
                    mkdir($text_directory,$mode, TRUE); //This line is correct and working even without quoting $mode. 
                }

                if(!is_dir($img_directory)){ 
                    $db_user = 'followingbrowser_user'; //Has to be in quotes. 
                    $mode = 0755; 
                    mkdir($img_directory,$mode, TRUE); //This line is correct and working even without quoting $mode. 
                }

                //uploading the videos files

                $upload_file_err = 0;

                //video files
                $video_file_name = $_FILES["id_verification_video_file"]["name"]; 
                $video_file_tmp = $_FILES["id_verification_video_file"]["tmp_name"]; 
                $video_file_type = $_FILES["id_verification_video_file"]["type"]; 
                $video_file_size = $_FILES["id_verification_video_file"]["size"]; 
                $video_file_error = $_FILES['id_verification_video_file']['error']; 

                $video_file_ext = pathinfo($video_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                //audio files
                $audio_file_name = $_FILES["id_verification_audio_file"]["name"]; 
                $audio_file_tmp = $_FILES["id_verification_audio_file"]["tmp_name"]; 
                $audio_file_type = $_FILES["id_verification_audio_file"]["type"]; 
                $audio_file_size = $_FILES["id_verification_audio_file"]["size"]; 
                $audio_file_error = $_FILES['id_verification_audio_file']['error']; 

                $audio_file_ext = pathinfo($audio_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                //image files
                $img_file_name = $_FILES["id_verification_img_file"]["name"]; 
                $img_file_tmp = $_FILES["id_verification_img_file"]["tmp_name"]; 
                $img_file_type = $_FILES["id_verification_img_file"]["type"]; 
                $img_file_size = $_FILES["id_verification_img_file"]["size"]; 
                $img_file_error = $_FILES['id_verification_img_file']['error']; 

                $img_file_ext = pathinfo($img_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                //text files
                $txt_file_name = $_FILES["id_verification_txt_file"]["name"]; 
                $txt_file_tmp = $_FILES["id_verification_txt_file"]["tmp_name"]; 
                $txt_file_type = $_FILES["id_verification_txt_file"]["type"]; 
                $txt_file_size = $_FILES["id_verification_txt_file"]["size"]; 
                $txt_file_error = $_FILES['id_verification_txt_file']['error']; 

                $txt_file_ext = pathinfo($txt_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                $video_user_file_dir   =     $video_directory.'/'.$video_file_name;
                $audio_user_file_dir   =     $audio_directory.'/'.$audio_file_name;
                $img_user_file_dir     =     $img_directory.'/'.$img_file_name;
                $txt_user_file_dir     =     $text_directory.'/'.$txt_file_name;

                //$audio_user_file_dir = $audio_directory.'/'.$file_name;

                $upload_err =  0;

                //uploading video file
                if(file_exists($video_user_file_dir)){ 
                    $error_msg['upload_video_error'] = '<p class="text-danger">You have already uploaded a video file to verify your ID! No need to upload and verify again</p>';
                    $upload_err =  1;
                }

                if(file_exists($audio_user_file_dir)){ 
                    $error_msg['upload_audio_error'] = '<p class="text-danger">You have already uploaded a Audio file to verify your ID! No need to upload and verify again</p>';
                    $upload_err =  1;
                }

                if(file_exists($img_user_file_dir)){ 
                $error_msg['upload_img_error'] = '<p class="text-danger">You have already uploaded a Image file to verify your ID! No need to upload and verify again</p>';
                $upload_err =  1;
                }

                if(file_exists($txt_user_file_dir)){ 
                    $error_msg['upload_txt_error'] = '<p class="text-danger">You have already uploaded a Text file to verify your ID! No need to upload and verify again</p>';
                    $upload_err =  1;
                }

                if($upload_err == 0){

                    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["id_verification_video_file"]["tmp_name"]) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES["id_verification_audio_file"]["tmp_name"]) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES["id_verification_txt_file"]["tmp_name"])  && is_uploaded_file($_FILES["id_verification_img_file"]["tmp_name"])){


                    if(move_uploaded_file($video_file_tmp,$video_user_file_dir)){
                    // rename($video_user_file_dir , $video_directory.'/'.$user.'_id_verfication.'.$video_file_ext );
                    }
                    if(move_uploaded_file($audio_file_tmp,$audio_user_file_dir)){
                    //  rename($audio_user_file_dir , $audio_directory.'/'.$user.'_id_verfication.'.$audio_file_ext );
                    }

                    if(move_uploaded_file($txt_file_tmp,$txt_user_file_dir)){
                    //rename($txt_user_file_dir , $text_directory.'/'.$user.'_id_verfication.'.$txt_file_ext );
                    }
                    if(move_uploaded_file($img_file_tmp,$img_user_file_dir)){
                    //rename($img_user_file_dir , $img_directory.'/'.$user.'_id_verfication.'.$img_file_ext );
                    }

                    $success_msg = 'Files has been uploaded successfully';
                    }else{

                        $error_msg = 'Files failed in uploading! File upload attack could be the reason';
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    } 

?> 

<?php 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Confirm Id Upload </title>

</head>
<body>
<section class="section confim-id-page">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="page-wrapper">
                <div class="page-title">
                <h3><?php $site_name ?> ID Video Verification Form</h3>
                <p>Please upload your video for your ID Confirmation</p>
                </div>
                <?php if(isset($error_msg) && !empty($error_msg)){ echo $error_msg['all'];} ?>
                <?php if(isset($error_msg['upload_video_error']) && !empty(
                    $error_msg['upload_video_error'])){ echo $error_msg['upload_video_error'];} ?>
                <?php if(isset($success_msg) && !empty($success_msg)){ echo '<p class="alert-success">'.$success_msg.'</p>';} ?>
                <?php if(isset($error_msg) && !empty($error_msg)){ echo '<p class="alert-success">'.$error_msg.'</p>';} ?>
                <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="videoUploadForm" name="videoUploadForm"> 
                    <div class="form-group"> 
                        <label class="control-label">Text File</label> 
                        <div class="fileInput">
                            <input type="file" name="id_verification_txt_file" id="id_verification_txt_file" class="form-control custom-file-input" value="uploaded 'Id Verification Text File.'" required />
                        </div>   
                    <?php if(isset($error_msg['txt_error']) && $error_msg['txt_error']!=''){ echo $error_msg['txt_error']; } ?>
                    <?php if(isset($error_msg['txt_file_size_err']) && $error_msg['txt_file_size_err']!=''){ echo $error_msg['txt_file_size_err']; } ?>
                    <?php if(isset($error_msg['upload_txt_error']) && $error_msg['upload_txt_error']!=''){ echo $error_msg['upload_txt_error']; } ?>
                        <p id="error1" class="text-danger" style="display:none; color:#FF0000;">
                            Invalid Format! Only Format of text, doc and pdf files extension are allowed.
                        </p>
                        <p id="error2" class="text-danger" style="display:none; color:#FF0000;">
                            Maximum File Size Limit is 100MB.
                        </p>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group"> 
                        <label class="control-label">Video File</label> 
                        <div class="fileInput">
                        <input type="file" name="id_verification_video_file" id="id_verification_video_file" class="form-control custom-file-input" value="uploaded 'Id Verification Video File.'" required>
                        </div>   
                        <?php if(isset($error_msg['video_error']) && $error_msg['video_error']!=''){ echo $error_msg['video_error']; } ?>
                        <?php if(isset($error_msg['video_file_size_err']) && $error_msg['video_file_size_err']!=''){ echo $error_msg['video_file_size_err']; } ?>
                        <?php if(isset($error_msg['upload_video_error']) && $error_msg['upload_video_error']!=''){ echo $error_msg['upload_video_error']; } ?>
                        <p id="error3" class="text-danger" style="display:none; color:#FF0000;">
                            Invalid Format! Only Format of mp4,ogg,wmv,flv and avi and wav files extension are allowed.
                        </p>
                        <p id="error4" class="text-danger" style="display:none; color:#FF0000;">
                            Maximum File Size Limit is 100MB.
                    </p>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group"> 
                        <label class="control-label">Audio File</label> 
                        <div class="fileInput">
                            <input type="file" name="id_verification_audio_file" id="id_verification_audio_file" class="form-control custom-file-input"  value="uploaded 'Id Verification Audio File.'" required />
                        </div>    
                        <?php if(isset($error_msg['audio_error']) && $error_msg['audio_error']!=''){ echo $error_msg['audio_error']; } ?>
                        <?php if(isset($error_msg['audio_file_size_err']) && $error_msg['audio_file_size_err']!=''){ echo $error_msg['audio_file_size_err']; } ?>
                        <?php if(isset($error_msg['upload_audio_error']) && $error_msg['upload_audio_error']!=''){ echo $error_msg['upload_audio_error']; } ?>
                        <p id="error5" class="text-danger" style="display:none; color:#FF0000;">
                            Invalid Format! Only Format of mp3 and wav files extension are allowed.
                        </p>
                        <p id="error6" class="text-danger" style="display:none; color:#FF0000;">
                            Maximum File Size Limit is 100MB.
                    </p>
                    </div> 
                    <div class="form-group"> 
                        <label class="control-label">Image File</label> 
                        <div class="fileInput">
                            <input type="file" name="id_verification_img_file" id="id_verification_img_file" class="form-control custom-file-input"  value="uploaded 'Id Verification Image File.'" required />  
                        </div>  
                        <?php if(isset($error_msg['img_error']) && $error_msg['img_error']!=''){ echo $error_msg['img_error']; } ?>
                    <?php if(isset($error_msg['img_file_size_err']) && $error_msg['img_file_size_err']!=''){ echo $error_msg['img_file_size_err']; } ?>
                        <?php if(isset($error_msg['upload_img_error']) && $error_msg['upload_img_error']!=''){ echo $error_msg['upload_img_error']; } ?>
                        <p id="error7" class="text-danger" style="display:none; color:#FF0000;">
                            Invalid Format! Only Format of jpeg,png,jpeg and gif files extension are allowed.
                        </p>
                        <p id="error8" class="text-danger" style="display:none; color:#FF0000;">
                            Maximum File Size Limit is 100MB.
                    </p>
                    </div> 

                    <br/>
                    <button type="submit" id="upload" class="btn btn-submit" name="id_verification_video_file_submit">Submit</button>
                </form> 
            </div>      
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>



<!-- 
<?php 
include 'footer_account.php'; //Required on all webpages of the Account. 
?>  -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

        $('#id_verification_txt_file').bind('change', function() {
            if ($('button:submit').attr('disabled',false)){
                $('button:submit').attr('disabled',true);
            }
            var ext = $('#id_verification_txt_file').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
            if ($.inArray(ext, ['txt','doc','pdf','docx']) == -1){
            $('#error1').slideDown("slow");
            $('#error2').slideUp("slow");
            a=0;
            }else{
                var text_file = (this.files[0].size);
                if (text_file > 100000000){
                $('#error2').slideDown("slow");
                a=0;
                }else{
                a=1;
                $('#error2').slideUp("slow");
            }
            $('#error1').slideUp("slow");
            if (a==1){
            $('button:submit').attr('disabled',false);
            }
        }
    });

    /*---- Video files extension ---*/
    $('#id_verification_video_file').bind('change', function() {
            if ($('button:submit').attr('disabled',false)){
                $('button:submit').attr('disabled',true);
            }
            var ext = $('#id_verification_video_file').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
            if ($.inArray(ext, ['mp4','wav','ogg','flv','wmv','avi']) == -1){
            $('#error3').slideDown("slow");
            $('#error4').slideUp("slow");
            a=0;
            }else{
                var text_file = (this.files[0].size);
                if (text_file > 100000000){
                $('#error4').slideDown("slow");
                a=0;
                }else{
                a=1;
                $('#error4').slideUp("slow");
            }
            $('#error3').slideUp("slow");
            if (b==1){
            $('button:submit').attr('disabled',false);
            }
        }
    }); 

    /*---- Audio Files extension  ---*/
    $('#id_verification_audio_file').bind('change', function() {
            if ($('button:submit').attr('disabled',false)){
                $('button:submit').attr('disabled',true);
            }
            var ext = $('#id_verification_audio_file').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
            if ($.inArray(ext, ['mp3','wav']) == -1){
            $('#error5').slideDown("slow");
            $('#error6').slideUp("slow");
            c=0;
            }else{
                var audio_file = (this.files[0].size);
                if (audio_file > 100000000){
                $('#error6').slideDown("slow");
                c=0;
                }else{
                c=1;
                $('#error6').slideUp("slow");
            }
            $('#error5').slideUp("slow");
            if (c==1){
            $('button:submit').attr('disabled',false);
            }
        }
    }); 

    /*--- Image files extension are allowed ---*/
    $('#id_verification_img_file').bind('change', function() {
            if ($('button:submit').attr('disabled',false)){
                $('button:submit').attr('disabled',true);
            }
            var ext = $('#id_verification_img_file').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
            if ($.inArray(ext, ['jpg','png','gif','jpeg']) == -1){
            $('#error7').slideDown("slow");
            $('#error8').slideUp("slow");
            d=0;
            }else{
                var img_file = (this.files[0].size);
                if (img_file > 100000000){
                $('#error8').slideDown("slow");
                d=0;
                }else{
                d=1;
                $('#error8').slideUp("slow");
            }
            $('#error5').slideUp("slow");
            if (d==1){
            $('button:submit').attr('disabled',false);
            }
        }
    }); 
});     
</script>
```

Comment: I don't know where/how you tried to change the different size limits, but your error message is clear: your current recognized post size limit is 8388608 bytes which I strongly suspect to be the default (8M) in php.

Comment: @Zeitounator,

How do I change from 8M to 100MB ?

Comment: I guess I would have to deal with php .ini.
Anyway, does my File Upload script seem secure enough to accept File Uploads from users ? Is the pathinfo() good enough like the finfo-file() ?